# Is MMX better than Delphi's own modelling?

Tags: delphi, modeling

I'm using  2010 Enterprise, so I have all the modeling tools available. But I still seldom use them. I write the objects myself, setters, getters... I want to start using modeling besides class diagrams. Should I opt for Delphi's own implementation or perhaps try MMX. What other features does it bring to the table?
Thnx.

Comment: I think you mean ModelMaker. MMX is a different product from the same company.

Comment: No I didn't think about ModelMaker. I was thinking about the tool to reduce coding on adding properties and such.

Comment: Link to this product: http://www.modelmakertools.com/code-explorer/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

MMX is a great tool for coding OOP, it improves the productivity when you get used to this  features.

I don't think it replaces a Modeling Tool, I think MMX help you to write OOP code, refactory, navigate and inspect code, I can't imagine another tool to improve OOP coding in Delphi IDE like MMX does.

Delphi Templates can help you coding, is great and I do like, but MMX have a lot of "wizards" done, and I can't imagine how to implement some MMX actions using templates.

I use Delphi Modeling and MMX for coding, not only OOP, but to study and undertand 3th party units.

My favorites features:

- Unit visualization and navigation
- Class/properties creating/editing
- method parameter editing
- copy/cut/past classes/properties/methods
- local var creation and editing
- scope renaming
- Live Metrics, "I use this a LOT"
- Sometimes I use live documentation

To me, MMX is a must have expert.

Comment: Interesting tool. ModelMaker greatly improved from the last time I tried it (around 1997 - IIRC, something like a Code Explorer ancestor was bundled with ModelMaker).

Comment: Yes, this tool is a great idea, smoth integrated to IDE. I really enjoy use MMX.